# `canonical-livepatch enable` command seems to be hanging -- how can I figure out why?

Tags: 18.04, canonical-livepatch

I am setting up a brand new Ubuntu 18.04 (on a VPS) -- CLI only, no GUI. From a clean slate, the only things I've done so far is upgrade various apt packages, installed `snapd`, and ran `sudo canonical-livepatch enable $my_token`. The command appears to be hanging, and I have no insight into why it's just hanging there. Is there a way to turn on a verbose mode to see what errors it might be encountering? Or some other way to figure out what's going on and how I can enable live-patching?

Comment: Have you done `sudo canonical-livepatch config` or `sudo canonical-livepatch status`? Have you signed into your Ubuntu One account?

Comment: @heynnema: `sudo canonical-livepatch config` outputs:
```
# sudo canonical-livepatch config
http-proxy: ""
https-proxy: ""
no-proxy: ""
remote-server: https://livepatch.canonical.com
ca-certs: ""
check-interval: 60  # minutes
```
`sudo canonical-livepatch status` outputs

```
Machine is not enabled. Please run 'sudo canonical-livepatch enable' with the
token obtained from https://ubuntu.com/livepatch.
```

I did log into my Ubuntu One account and got the token from that location.

Comment: Then it's over my head. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this same issue on my fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install on a VPS.

According to `snap logs canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd`, this was due to:

```
bad temporary server status 500 (URL: https://livepatch.canonical.com/api/machine-tokens) server response: machine token already exists
```

This can be fixed by generating a new machine token before re-running `canonical-livepatch enable <token>`:

```
rm /etc/machine-id
systemd-machine-id-setup
```

However, in my case, the generated token was the same each time since it was using the  D-Bus machine ID, so I had to remove that first so that it uses the KVM UUID instead:

```
rm /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
rm /etc/machine-id
systemd-machine-id-setup
dbus-uuidgen --ensure
```

The last line just copies the new machine ID over to the first file deleted.